# Recreate a distribution with known mean, scatter, skewness and kurtosis in Python

Tags: normal-distribution, probability-distribution, kurtosis

So basically, I was reading a paper about simulated disk stars and their relation with different parameters (I'm particulary interested in the abundance). In one of the plots, they showed the abundace of [Fe/H] vs # (counts), and gave the results of their data's parameters, which were Mean 0.04, Scatter 0.17, Skewness -1.55 and Kurtosis 6.62. I've been trying to recreate their plot using the following code, but I have not been able to deal with the Kurtosis parameter.

I tried using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm, skewnorm
from scipy.stats import kurtosis

# Parameter value
mean = 0.04
scatter = 0.17
skewness = -1.55
kurtosis = 6.62

# Generating data to plot
x = np.linspace(mean - 4 * scatter, mean + 4 * scatter, 1000)
y = skewnorm.pdf(x, skewness, loc=mean, scale=mean)

# Plotting
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Probability density')
plt.title('Distribution')
#plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This code plots me a distribution where I can see how the skewness affects it, but I still haven't found a way to the same with the kurtosis. I'd like to do both in just one distribution. I searched for some info, but most of them just showed me how to calculate it from the data, but I want to plot a distribution already knowing the parameters.

Comment: Skew normal distribution defined by three parameters, which could be inferfed from mean, stddev, and skew. It means kurtosis is NOT an independent value, completely defined by abovementioned three parameters. You have to use 4-parametric distribution